# Best way to programatically send jobs to a hardware printer?

Tags: web-applications, command-line, printing

I deal with a lot of print jobs and I'm trying to figure out how to write a script that will print out any file I give it and support a wide range of formats including PDF, TXT, DOCX, etc. Anyone know some good printing libraries? I was warned to stay away from Java.. thanks!

EDIT: I am considering to write a command-line script then perhaps moving it to web for ease.

Platform is Ubuntu.

Comment: Why have you tagged this with web-applications? What's the relevance?

Comment: @Oded I'm deciding between having a commandline script or something I can access through a browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends upon the operating system and even the application kind (if the application is web-based, the printing should often be at the browser side, not inside the server).

On Linux, recent graphical toolkits (GTK3 or QT4 in particular) have API to deal with printers (and both Qt & Gtk are ported to Windows), e.g. [QPrinter](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qprinter.html), [Gtk Printing](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/unstable/Printing.html) and related stuff. And a program can always fork a `lpr` or `lp` or `a2ps` command (perhaps using `popen`). The `a2ps` utility is able to print a lot of formats.

On Windows (outside of GTK or Qt) I have no idea, because I never use Windows.

Comment: Thank you I will clarify my question.

Comment: I think I answered it, since Ubuntu is a Linux.